# Remark Added By Closing Question Based On Duplicate

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

Can we please rephrase (capital P)

> possible duplicate of

into

> Possible duplicate of

See screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already has been mentioned three years ago and it was marked status-declined. The reasoning was a little weird, in my opinion. I'm waiting to hear the thoughts from the current SE staff.

[Capitalize "possible" in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl)

Comment: Perhaps it's time to make some noice. Did you upvote? Three years is a long time....

Comment: It seems we will leave it as it is. Can you add the status declined?